# Merge lists of complex dicts with arbitrary keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, avro

I have this code:

```
dotteds = ["apple.orange.banana", "a.b.c", "a.b.d"]

name = "name"
avtype = "type"
fields = "fields"


main_dictionary_list = []

for x in dotteds:

    split_name = x.split('.')
    if len(split_name) > 1:
        value = {name: split_name[-1], avtype: 'string'}
        dicts = []
        for y in split_name:
            dicts.append({name: y, avtype: {name: y, avtype: "record", fields: []}})
        dicts[-1] = value

        value = value['name']+split_name[-1]

        for z in reversed(range(len(dicts))):
            if z != 0:
                dicts[z - 1]['type']['fields'].append(dicts[z])

        main_dictionary_list.append(dicts[0])

    else:
        dicts = []
        value = {name: split_name[-1], avtype: 'string'}
        dicts.append(value)
        main_dictionary_list.append(dicts[0])

print(main_dictionary_list)
```

Which gives me an output like this:

```
[{
        'name': 'apple',
        'type': {
            'name': 'apple',
            'type': 'record',
            'fields': [{
                    'name': 'orange',
                    'type': {
                        'name': 'orange',
                        'type': 'record',
                        'fields': [{
                                'name': 'banana',
                                'type': 'string'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        'name': 'a',
        'type': {
            'name': 'a',
            'type': 'record',
            'fields': [{
                    'name': 'b',
                    'type': {
                        'name': 'b',
                        'type': 'record',
                        'fields': [{
                                'name': 'c',
                                'type': 'string'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        'name': 'a',
        'type': {
            'name': 'a',
            'type': 'record',
            'fields': [{
                    'name': 'b',
                    'type': {
                        'name': 'b',
                        'type': 'record',
                        'fields': [{
                                'name': 'd',
                                'type': 'string'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Ideally I need:

```
[{
        'name': 'apple',
        'type': {
            'name': 'apple',
            'type': 'record',
            'fields': [{
                    'name': 'orange',
                    'type': {
                        'name': 'orange',
                        'type': 'record',
                        'fields': [{
                                'name': 'banana',
                                'type': 'string'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        'name': 'a',
        'type': {
            'name': 'a',
            'type': 'record',
            'fields': [{
                    'name': 'b',
                    'type': {
                        'name': 'b',
                        'type': 'record',
                        'fields': [{
                                'name': 'c',
                                'type': 'string'
                            }, 
                            {
                                'name': 'd',
                                'type': 'string'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I need to be able to do this with any number of combinations:

**apple.orange.banana, a.b.c, a.b.d, a.b.q.e.a.s.d, etc.**

I cannot figure out how to combine the similar 'name: key' combinations. It's intended to be avro format.

I have also tried making the dotted values into a dictionary which is a bit of trouble on its own.

Comment: Can you take a step back, and provide a bit more context/background for this?

Comment: Have a look at https://avro4s-ui.landoop.com/ I want to do this but based on dotted names, and also plug in my own type values. JSON ---> Avro schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def group(vals, last=None):
   if any(len(i) == 1 for i in vals):
      return [{'name':last, 'type':{'name':last, 'type':'record', 'fields':[{'name':i[0], 'type':'string'} if len(i) == 1 else group([i], i[0])[0] for i in vals]}}]
   _d = defaultdict(list)
   for i in vals:
      _d[i[0]].append(i[1:])
   return [{'name':a, 'type':group(b, last=a)} if last is None else 
              {'name':last, 'type':'record', 'fields':group(b, last=a)} for a, b in _d.items()]
```

---

```
import json
vals = ['apple.orange.banana', 'a.b.c', 'a.b.d']
print(json.dumps(group([i.split('.') for i in vals]), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "type": [
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "orange",
                    "type": {
                        "name": "orange",
                        "type": "record",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "banana",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "a",
    "type": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "b",
                    "type": {
                        "name": "b",
                        "type": "record",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "c",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "d",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
   }
]
```

---

```
vals = ['asd.2', 'asd.3', 'asd.5.3.4']
print(json.dumps(group([i.split('.') for i in vals]), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "asd",
    "type": [
        {
            "name": "asd",
            "type": {
                "name": "asd",
                "type": "record",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "2",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "3",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "5",
                        "type": "record",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "5",
                                "type": "record",
                                "fields": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "3",
                                        "type": {
                                            "name": "3",
                                            "type": "record",
                                            "fields": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "4",
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: On further inspection this is close, but not perfect. Try these values: asd.2, asd.3, asd.5.3.4

Comment: @tsai9_9 What is your desired output for those values?

Comment: I want it to continue: "name": "asd", "type": { "name": asd", "type": "record", "fields" : [{"name": "2", "type":"string"},{"name": "3", "type": "string"}, {"name":"5", "type":{"name":"5", "type": "record", "fields":["name": "3", "type": {"name":"3", "type": "record", "fields": ["name": "4", "type": "string"]}]}]}}]. You nearly have it right, because it works when you don't have varying lengths, (if you do asd.2 and asd.3 it will work, if you do asd.5.3.4 and asd.3 it will say the index is out of range), I just need it to work when you put both lengths in and still combine them.

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: @tsai9_9 Glad to help!